# Allowing only past date and today's date in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using VB.net as well as Jquery Datepicker for getting dates.

In my VB.net code

```
<tr>
    <td>
        DateOfReceiving:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateOfReceivingTextBox" runat="server"
                     CssClass="pastdatepicker" 
                     Text="DateOfReceiving" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to allow enter user only todays date or past date with format `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want vb.net custom validation for that.

Please help to write vb.net regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a RangeValidator and a bit of VB.NET code:

```
<tr>    
    <td>DateOfReceiving:</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateOfReceivingTextBox" runat="server"  
                     CssClass="pastdatepicker" 
                     Text="DateOfReceiving" />

        <asp:rangevalidator runat="server" ID="DateRangeValidator"
                            ControlToValidate="DateofReceivingTextBox"
                            ErrorMessage="Date must be in the past"  
                            Display="Dynamic" Type="Date"  />

    </td>
</tr>
```

Set the range for the validator in your code-behind, most likely in your Page_Load:

```
DateRangeValidator.MinimumValue = Date.MinValue.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
DateRangeValidator.MaximumValue = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to want to use a regular expression for this.

If you want to do this server-side, you should look into creating validation controls. I've never done this in VB.NET (simply because I've never used VB.NET - I'm more comfortable with C#), but [this page](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=197&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) appears to be a good starting point. You are going to want to inherit from and override methods in the [`BaseValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) class.

I don't usually write client-side code unless I have to, but it looks like jQuery supports [form validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) as well. However, as brad.huffman pointed out in the comments, you probably want to avoid doing date/time validation on the client side as you can't control your user's date/time settings - they could be incorrect.

Comment: Definitely going to want to do this server side as client side, you'd be relying on the user's machine to have the date set properly.